# Accessing php file on JAVA without any parameters given

Tags: java, android, json

my first question here so sorry if i mess things up.

I need to access a link of a php file to receive JSON from there but without passing any parameters to it. Earlier I did same thing but with passing parameters and a can't just delete void with MAP where I usually specified them.

```
public void LoadingBoosters(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"starting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.URL_GET_BOOSTERS,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {       
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        if (jsonObject.getInt("error") == 0) {
                            //Type
                          }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject.getString("error"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FAILED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("error", e.toString(), e);
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error connection!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking but if by link you mean a URL it sounds like you just need to change the URL.

Comment: Don't override `getParams` and use default implementation (which returns null).

Comment: Oh, I though "Map" is a obligatory method, now I just removed it and it works, thanks for hint.